# Facebook Open Graph Views

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get the number of views of an Open Graph Object, using just the facebook API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [Insights for Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/insights/) are currently only available through the Insights dashboard, not any API yet.

Given that the OG object is presumably on your server, you should be able to track individual views of that object with some simple tracking code.